# Encrypt folders with a nice gui

Tags: encryption, ubuntu-gnome, ecryptfs, encfs

I am currently using encfs 1.7.4 with gnome encfs manager 1.8.17 to encrypt my confidential files. This manager has quite a nice gui that allows me to quickly mount available (previously mounted) encrypted folders.

[image: encfs manager]

I know that encfs has several security problems but for a drive that remains in my personal possession this doesn't pose a serious security risk.
However I need to send someone confidential (personal) files and I feel that encfs isn't secure enough to expose the encrypted files to the internet.
I wanted to use ecryptfs for these files. and since I am going to use ecryptfs anyway I might as well go safe and replace encfs entirely. **Does anyone know of a decent gui for ecryptfs comparable to encfs manager?**

Comment: Maybe this one: http://linuxsoft.cern.ch/cern/slc57/i386/yum/updates/repoview/ecryptfs-utils-gui.html will work? It's older but it's made by smart guys (at CERN).

Comment: How about gpg/pgp of an archive (tar.gz, tar.xz, 7z, ...) for just an occasional sharing

Comment: that cern program was made quite casually for internal use and (for me) requires more work than using the terminal. 
@Xen2050: Sharing isn't the problem. I am perfectly capable of using the terminal to encrypt my files it's just that I have a few folders that I frequently update and would like to access easily (like I can with encfs manager).